# AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, themes

i recently installed the ttkthemes package for my tkinter project, and so i figured everything that says `tk` in my code should be replaced with `ttk` but for some reason i get the error `AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'Tk`. Please help, Thanks for any help in advance.
Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk

class SeaofBTCapp(ttk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Task, YourAdressess):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        # for frame in self.frames.values():
        # frame.grid_remove()

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.ttkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("1024x720")
        frame.configure(bg='#333130')



class Task(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        c = Canvas(self, height=50, width=102400, bg="#333130")
        c.pack()
        taskbutton = ttk.Button(self, text='Task', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Task))
        taskbutton_window = c.create_window(10, 12.5, anchor=ttk.NW, window=taskbutton)
        adressbutton = ttk.Button(self, text='Your Adressess', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(YourAdressess))
        adressbutton_window = c.create_window(104, 12.5, anchor=ttk.NW, window=adressbutton)

class YourAdressess(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        c = Canvas(self, height=50, width=1024, bg="#333130")
        c.pack()
        taskbutton = ttk.Button(self, text='Task', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Task))
        taskbutton_window = c.create_window(10, 12.5, anchor=ttk.NW, window=taskbutton)
        adressbutton = ttk.Button(self, text='Your Adressess', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(YourAdressess))
        adressbutton_window = c.create_window(104, 12.5, anchor=ttk.NW, window=adressbutton)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you precisely what is wrong. ttk does not have a class named `Tk`. You must use the one that comes from the tkinter module.

Since you did a wildcard import of tkinter, you can use `Tk`:

```
class SeaofBTCapp(Tk):
```

Comment: Or you have to install ```ttkthemes``` with pip :)

Comment: @TheMaker: even with that, ttk doesn’t have the class `Tk`

Comment: True, but if you don't install ttkthemes, you will get a bigger error, right?